# Cross trigger jquery code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to have a scalable image that will be centered on an scalable `<div>` at this point I have a `<div>` used as wrapper, the `<div>` that is scalable and holds the image. And I have some jquery code that calculates the width of the `<body>` and gets the amount of space available for the `<div>/<img />`. The site content is 745px; so the rest of the window will be left for the div and image.
This is what I have for now:

```
<div class="ad_banner_holder" id="ad_banner_holder" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="ad_banner" id="ad_banner" style="background: white; text-align: center; position: absolute;">
        <a href="http://www.finconsult.ro/" target="_blank"><img id="the_ad" style="position: fixed; max-width: 800px; margin-top: 82px;" src="http://ww1.particularul.ro/images/ads/3rdtry2.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        var adwidth = $("body").width();
        adwidth = adwidth - 760;
        $("#the_ad").css("width", adwidth);
        $("#ad_banner").css("width", adwidth);
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var adwidth = $("body").width();
        adwidth = adwidth - 760;
        $("#ad_banner").css("width", adwidth);

    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var adwidth = $("#ad_banner").width();
        $("#the_ad").css("width", adwidth);

    });
</script>
```

The thing is that the script works perfect when the browser is resizes.
When you refresh the page the browser centers the image then it resize it from the point where it is to the right (getting away from the center point); I don't understand why the same code doesn't work with different triggers.

Also I tried to change the trigger for the image resize to `.hover()` and it's acting the same: the centered image has it's width changed and moves away from the center.

Any help/explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: your code seems to have two resize functions..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do you have two resize functions but you should just use standard jquery ready to detect when the page has loaded.

```
$(function() {
    var adwidth = $("body").width();
    adwidth = adwidth - 760;
    $("#the_ad").css("width", adwidth);
    $("#ad_banner").css("width", adwidth);

    //combine the two resize handlers

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var adwidth = $("body").width();
        adwidth = adwidth - 760;
        $("#ad_banner").css("width", adwidth);

    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var adwidth = $("#ad_banner").width();
        $("#the_ad").css("width", adwidth);

    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, this code worked, I tried combining the resize but with different triggers, this worked. Thenk you

Comment: The code is not triggering in all pages first I assumed it might be another script that might have invalid javascript that is causing this but what happens is quite interesting... if I refresh the page several times one out of a lot the code runs ok. I need to inform that the page loads very slow, can the jquery .ready() function time out?

Comment: The timeout is hard to pinpoint without seeing more.  You need to combine the two resize functions to reduce unwanted behavior as well.  The initial question may be addressed here but there is probably a more simple solution to your desired functionality through CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine everything :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var adwidth; // can be used in this scope

        // your resize function is factorized
        function resizeAd(){ 
            adwidth = $("body").width() - 760;
            $("#the_ad").css("width", adwidth);
            $("#ad_banner").css("width", adwidth);
        }

        // launched at DOM ready and on window's resize event
        resizeAd();
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            resizeAd();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not resizing the image (loads it's default size), it's not resizing the ad_banner div, r0m4n code worked and thank you a lot for taking time on this.

Comment: Yup, but your and his code are redundant. At least, factorize a little, I'll update my answer to show you.

Comment: I tried the code, it's not triggering at .redy() it's not triggering at resize; I checked it and it should run but it doesn't. The first code works in some pages but in other it doesn't. For those pages where the script is not running I suspect some external javascript errors but on the page where the first script works your's should work also... thnx for your help.